# Commands hidden in CodeName one Android build

Tags: lwuit, codenameone

I am trying to port my LWUIT app to [CodeName one](http://www.codenameone.com).

My LWUIT form had 2 commands. These were seen at the bottom of the form in LWUIT.

In codename one's android build these commands are not visible at the bottom of the screen.

Why does this happen and How do i fix this?

Blackberry Screen/Android/I Pad ...no commands can be seen

[image]

Here is your usual phone and commands can be seen

What could be the issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blackberry and Android have a menu button, the commands are in there.

In iPhone/iPad the commands will appear in a form but not in a dialog where they must be embedded as buttons. I suggest you use the static show method of dialog that accepts commands, this will work seamlessly across devices.

Comment: haha...menu! ok... I Don't have an android ...so was just testing with the emulator...great ..got it working now :)